# C# / LINQ fastest way of comparing two lists and assigning value

Tags: c#, linq, list, c#-4.0, iequalitycomparer

I have made a code which basically compares two lists in C#. First list contains properties like this:

- ItemID
- TotalViews

First list lacks values for TotalViews so I'm assigning them from 2nd list which has these props:

- ItemID
- HitCount // this is property for TotalViews that needs to be assigned

The code is as following:

```
foreach (var item in parsedMerchantData)
{
    var itemInB = HitCountItemIDS.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ItemID == item.ItemID);
    if (itemInB != null)
    {
        if (itemInB.HitCount != -1)
        {
            item.TotalViews = itemInB.HitCount;
        }
        else
        {
            item.TotalViews = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any more efficient way to write this using LINQ or implementing a custom comparer which would work faster on larger lists that contains sometimes 100000 items in themselves?

Comment: Please put more efforts into formatting your question in future. You've asked over 100 questions now - that's *plenty* of time to get to grips with how Markdown works. There's on excuse for poor formatting as your post had before I fixed it.

Comment: It would also really help if you'd provide a [mcve]. There are various ways of approaching this... a dictionary would be an obvious starting point, but we don't know whether there could be two elements in `HitCountItemIDS` with the same ID, for one thing.

Comment: HitCountItemIDS  can't contain duplicate items, all are unique, same as first list. And yes my apologies I shall put more effort into it in future =)

Comment: One optimization from the top of my head is sorting two lists by ID and doing something like MergeSort where you step through both lists at once. LINQ is not meant to be the *fastest* way, but rather quick-to-write and readable.

Comment: @DmytroBogatov exactly that was my first idea when I started to write it, but as the time went on i figured this is not a good idea at all... Could you show me a practical example for my case how it can be done?

Comment: Fastest method would be to create a dictionary of HitCountItemIDS by ID before the for loop. Your search for comparison is taking an average of N/2 lookups to find each item.  A Dictionary is a hash which will take Log2(N) to locate each item.  Much faster.

Comment: @jdweng could you show me a practical example =) ?

Comment: If You would have one or both list sorted, you could make a better performance of it. Depends how You cam hold the result and if You have index over them.

Comment: Dictionary<string, ABC_TYPE> dict = HitCountItemID.GropupBy(x => x.ItemID, y => y).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());  Lookup would be dict[item.Item]

Comment: @jdweng not sure what do I do then with this output type of dictionary...  I cant apply it to my list ? o.o

Comment: @Tatranskymedved Could you show me what you mean ?

Comment: @User987 just put an answer with pseudo-code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the pseudo-code:

```
var arr1 = parsedMerchantData.OrderBy(x => x.ItemID).ToArray();
var arr2 = HitCountItemID.OrderBy(x => x.ItemID).ToArray();

var i, j = 0;
while(i + j < arr1.Length() + arr2.Length()) // or similar condition
{
    if (arr1[i].ItemID < arr2[j].ItemID) {
        if (i < arr1.Length() - 1) {
            i++;
        }
        continue;
    }

    if (arr1[i].ItemID > arr2[j].ItemID) {
        if (j < arr2.Length() - 1) {
            j++;
        }
        continue;
    }

    if (arr1[i].ItemID == arr2[j].ItemID) {
        arr1[i].TotalViews = arr2[j].HitCount != -1 ? arr2[j].HitCount : 0;
    }

    // Make sure you do not let i and j grow higher then lengths of arrays
}
```

The idea is to apply MergeSort algorithms.
As for complexity, you spend O(n * log(n)) sorting each list then O(n) going trough them. The total is O(n * log(n)) and it is the fastest way I see.

Comment: There is no need to sort in this case and the sorting adds Time.  Using a Linq GroupBy() should run quicker than c# code.

Answer (score 5):

This is like jdweng's answer, but slightly simpler and it won't throw an exception for missing item IDs:

```
var hitCountsById = HitCountItemIDS.ToDictionary(x => x.ItemID, x => x.HitCount);
foreach (var item in parsedMerchantData)
{
    int hitCount;
    // We don't care about the return value of TryGetValue here...
    hitCountsById.TryGetValue(item.ItemID, out hitCount);
    item.HitCount = hitCount == -1 ? 0 : hitCount;
}
```

This should be O(N+M) where N is the size of `HitCountItemIDs` and `M` is the size of `parsedMerchantData`... so should as the data gets bigger, it should grow more slowly than the merge-sort approach, and is definitely simpler code. (It doesn't require comparing item ID for ordering, either - just equality.)

Comment: Wow what a nice optimization, the best answer of all, very simple yet much much faster than my original ! =)

Answer (score 2):

Code would look like below.  Not sure what the type of HitCountItemID is.  If it is anonymous then just make 'var dict' :

```
Dictionary<string, ABC_TYPE> dict = HitCountItemID.GropupBy(x => x.ItemID, y => y).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault())
foreach (var item in parsedMerchantData)
{
    var itemInB = dict[item.ItemID];
    if (itemInB != null)
    {
        if (itemInB.HitCount != -1)
        {
            item.TotalViews = itemInB.HitCount;
        }
        else
        {
            item.TotalViews = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: would this be faster than Merge sort and other methods that people had mentioned?

Comment: @User987 - No, but certainly cleaner.

Comment: @DmytroBogatov does it matters if parsedMerchantData is concurrentbag or list? Right now as it is it is type of concurrentbag... Should I get faster performance if I had it cast into list?

Comment: @User987 - you cannot just *cast* to List, you will have to rebuild the structure, which has performance penalty. I do not know LINQ internal algorithms, but I feel like no, you should not convert to list. GroupBy will anyway traverse all elements regardless of the order.

Comment: This will go bang for any missing items - you need to use `TryGetValue` rather than the indexer. (But this is how I'd do it too - and it may very well be more efficient than the merge sort approach. It should be O(N+M), basically.) Given the claim that the item IDs are unique, you don't need the `GroupBy` call though - just `var dict = HitCountItemIDS.ToDictionary(x => x.ItemID);` In fact, you could even just use the hit count... will add an answer

Answer (score 2):

I assume You are holding 2 lists during the program run/collecting data, so You can sort them during insertion. Or if they are in DB and there is an Index on the ID it migh also work.

If so, You should be able to do just one run through each array, which would optimize the program really high (now you got about n^2 complexity depending on values), after you change You would have n.

```
int i = 0, j = 0;

while( i < parsedMerchantData.Count && j < HitCountItemIDS.Count)
{
    var item = parsedMerchantData[i];
    var itemInB = HitCountItemIDS[j];

    if (itemInB.ItemID == item.ItemID)
    {
        item.TotalViews = (itemInB.HitCount > 0) ? itemInB.HitCount : 0;
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    else if(itemInB.ItemID < item.ItemID)
        i++;
    else  //itemInB.ItemID > item.ItemID
        j++;
}
```

The code should look similar to the one above, You should add some more control about when it ends & what should happend with the rest values (this will stop once either `i` or `j` hit the end).